# Combine Subtract and Filter in Scala

Tags: list, scala, filter

I am trying to write a function in Scala which takes two integer lists `xs` and `ys` and does the following:

- subtracts element by element `ys` from `xs`. An example: `List(1,2,4)` and `List(3,2,1)` gets you `List(-2, 0, 3)`
- filters out all elements less than or equal to 0 from the list resulting from step 1.

I am trying to do this using the [list functions from the Scala Standard Library](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html)

```
object Solution {
  def combineSubAndFilter(xs: List[Int], ys: List[Int]) = ???
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why it didn't work? - BTW, what should happen if one list is shorter than the other? - PS: Hint `zip` + `map` + `filter`.

Comment: What if the lists aren't the same size?  Also, what did you try?

Comment: @PabloBiedma Ok so take a look to the docs especially to the methods I mentioned in my first comment. But, given what you said about assuming `0` then you need to use `zipAll` instead of `zip`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer, as suggested in the comments by @Luis is:

```
def combineSubAndFilter(xs: List[Int], ys: List[Int]) = xs.zipAll(ys, 0, 0).collect { case (x,y) if (x > y) => x-y }
```

From `zipAll` documentation:

> Returns a $coll formed from this $coll and another iterable collection by combining corresponding elements in pairs. If one of the two collections is shorter than the other, placeholder elements are used to extend the shorter collection to the length of the longer.

Code run can be found at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/GujgSu4lR8uhj7rfBXIsfQ/7).